# Texturing a VBO in OpenGL and LWJGL - crashing on start

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl, vbo

I'm writing a voxel engine in LWJGL and am trying to apply a single texture to the whole 16x16 chunk of cubes.  Each cube face should have a simple 32x32 dirt texture applied to it.  I can't for the life of me figure out what I could be doing wrong. It previously worked when applying a color to each cube face.

The program just crashes on start without giving any hint to what is going wrong.  If I modify the program to use colors again it loads just fine.

```
public void createChunk() {
    FloatBuffer vertexPositionData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(((12*6)*activateBlocks));
    FloatBuffer vertexTextureData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(((8*6)*activateBlocks));
    Random random = new Random();

    dirtTexture.bind();

    for (int x = 0; x < Constants.CHUNK_SIZE; x++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < Constants.CHUNK_SIZE; z++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < Constants.CHUNK_SIZE; y++) {

                if(occlusionCulling(x, y, z)) {
                    continue;
                }

                if(blocks[x][y][z].getActive()) {
                    putVertices((x*2)*Constants.BLOCK_SIZE, (-y*2)*Constants.BLOCK_SIZE, (z*2)*Constants.BLOCK_SIZE, vertexPositionData);

                    vertexTextureData.put(new float[]{
                            0.0f, 0.0f,
                            1.0f, 0.0f,
                            1.0f, 1.0f,
                            0.0f, 1.0f,

                            0.0f, 0.0f,
                            1.0f, 0.0f,
                            1.0f, 1.0f,
                            0.0f, 1.0f,

                            0.0f, 0.0f,
                            1.0f, 0.0f,
                            1.0f, 1.0f,
                            0.0f, 1.0f,

                            0.0f, 0.0f,
                            1.0f, 0.0f,
                            1.0f, 1.0f,
                            0.0f, 1.0f,

                            0.0f, 0.0f,
                            1.0f, 0.0f,
                            1.0f, 1.0f,
                            0.0f, 1.0f,

                            0.0f, 0.0f,
                            1.0f, 0.0f,
                            1.0f, 1.0f,
                            0.0f, 1.0f,
                    });

                }
            }
        }
    }

    vertexPositionData.flip();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOVertexHandle);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexPositionData, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    vertexTextureData.flip();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOTextureHandle);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexTextureData, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

public void drawChunk() {
    GL11.glPushMatrix();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOVertexHandle);
    GL11.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOTextureHandle);
    GL11.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);
    GL11.glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS, 0, ((24)*activateBlocks));

    GL11.glPopMatrix();

}
```

Comment: Not related, but why are you pushing and popping matrices in `drawChunk()`? It seems not necessary.

Comment: Try adding a call to `System.out.println(GLU.gluErrorString(GL11.glGetError()));` before and after every OpenGL call.

Comment: The pushing and popping of the matrices have been removed, thanks.  I have added the error call after every opengl call and every single one of them produces "No Error" before crashing.

Comment: Try setting break-points on every OpenGL call, so that we have to find the call which causes crash.

Comment: It looks like you forgot `glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)` before `glDrawArrays`, as well as disabling them after.

Comment: Also I don't see where you are setting your handles with `glGenBuffers()`.

Comment: I added `glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)` before drawing arrays but the crash still occurs.  I added break points to all the OpenGL calls and the error seems to be occurring at `GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS, 0, ((24)*activateBlocks));` odd.

Comment: I would double check that the amount of data you store in both the `vertexPositionData` and `vertexTextureData` buffers in `createChunk` matches the amount needed to match `activateBlocks`. I suspect that at least one of the buffers has too little data.